# How to install Git on an offline Windows computer?

Tags: windows, installation, git

I have a Windows computer not connected to the internet.

I tried to fun the exe to install git (located at https://git-scm.com/download/win?force_isolation=true)
It didn't work & had some error about being offline.

How can I install git on a windows computer which is offline?

Note: I saw the related post below, but I'm not interested in git.
How to install Github for Windows offline?

Comment: There's no "offline installer" but there's the portable version that likely suits your needs.

Comment: Hmm, Visual Studio Installer can install GIT as well as create "offline" installer. However if you are not interested in Visual Studio itself, then its quite an overkill.

Comment: Is there really no offline installer? Last time I used it, I was sure it was 100% self-contained. What was the actual error that you saw?

Comment: You can download Chocolatey [package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/git.install) and transfer the package to the machine and install it that way.  Your question is confusing you first indicate you are not interested in Github but then specifically ask how to install Github offline

Comment: You'll have to tell us specifically what the error message said.  Without that information, it's hard to help.